# ¿Cómo utilizar un array en una función en C# - Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

Esta es la manera en la que estoy recorriendo un array pero me pregunto si habrá una manera mucho mejor de optimizar el código en la función void numArray. Intenté utilizando el siguiente esquema: void numArray(int [] numArray, int b), pero no pude finalizarlo, no comprendí como darle continuación

```
void Start()
{
    numArray(12, 17, 19, 3);
}


bool evenNum = false;
void numArray(int x, int y, int z, int b)
{
    int[] numeros = { x, y, z };
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numeros[i] % b == 0)
        {
            evenNum = true;
            Debug.Log("El valor " + numeros[i] + " es par");
            Debug.Log(evenNum);
        }
        else
        {
            evenNum = false;
            Debug.Log("El valor " + numeros[i] + " no es par");
            Debug.Log(evenNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería bueno que expliques que es lo que querías hacer. Ahora mismo no sé si tu pregunta es como pasar un arreglo como parámetro de una función o si quieres sugerencias para tu código. En el último caso es posible que la pregunta termine cerrada por basarse en opiniones.

Comment: Sí, señor. ¿Cómo pasar un arreglo como parámetro de una función?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo definela pasandole un array en la funcion o una nueva lista

```
void numArray(int[] numeros,int b)
{

}
```

Cuando se use, solamente pasas el array:

```
var miArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
numArray(miArray, 1);
// o tambien
numArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 1);
```

Tambien de paso puedes recorrer ese array de la siguiente manera:

```
 void numArray(int[] numeros, int b)
 {
   foreach (var numero in numeros)
   {
     evenNum = numero % b == 0;
     Debug.Log("El valor" + numero + " " + (evenNum ? "es par" : "no es par"));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma en que se escriben los parámetros es indicando primero el tipo y luego el nombre, similar a la declaración de variables.

Para definir un parámetro array:

```
void funcion(int[] numeros){
     ...
}
```

Para llamarla:

```
static void Main(){
    funcion(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

    int[] arreglo = new int[] { 7, 5, 1, 8 };
    funcion(arreglo);
}
```

Comment: Cuando llamo a esa función, cómo agrego los valores, es la parte que no me queda clara. Por ejemplo. tengo void funcion (int[] numeros){...]. Si llamo a esa función desde el void Start(){funcion(???)},  ¿cómo agrego esos valores?

Comment: Ahí te dejé un ejemplo de como llamarla